# Dropdown list doesn't show data from connected database

Tags: php, html, ajax

I've create a dropdown list with all the product in my 'inventory' table. When a product is selected, it should display a table that shows the selling price and quantity of the product. But nothing happens when I select a product and I can't find the problem with my code.

DB name: nht

Table name: inventory

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KbjUc.png)

[Dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Ikv3.png)

[No results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXnWp.png)

Here's my code for the HTML:

```html
<html>
<head>
<script>
function showProduct(str) {
    if (str == "") {
        document.getElementById("txtid").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    } else {
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {

            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {

            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 30 && this.status == 200) {
   alert(this.responseText);
           document.getElementById("txtid").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET","getproduct.php?q="+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
</script>
<body>

<form>
<select name="id" onchange="showProduct(this.value)">
  <option value="">Select a product:</option>
  <option value="1">Alternator Assembly Fuso 4D30</option>
  <option value="2">Alternator Assembly Isuzu V-10</option>
  <option value="3">Alternator Assembly Hino JO8C</option>
  <option value="4">Alternator Assembly Isuzu 4BC2</option>
  <option value="5">Alternator Assembly Fuso 4HF1</option>
  <option value="6">Alternator Brush Toyota AN-11</option>
  <option value="7">Alternator Brush Isuzu AK-6</option>
  <option value="8">Alternator Brush Hino AD-6</option>
  <option value="9">Alternator Brush Fuso AM-22</option>
  <option value="10">Alternator Brush Fuso AH-18</option>
  <option value="11">Armature Assembly Fuso 4D50</option>
  <option value="12">Armature Assembly Isuzu V-10</option>
  <option value="13">Armature Assembly Fuso SDC9</option>
  <option value="14">Armature Assembly Fuso 6D22</option>
  <option value="15">Armature Assembly Hino JOSC </option>
  <option value="16">Solomoid Switch Isuzu S5-146</option>
  <option value="17">Solomoid Switch Fuso SS-1569</option>
  <option value="18">Solomoid Switch Hino SS-2715</option>
  <option value="19">Solomoid Switch Toyota SS-1200</option>
  <option value="20">Solomoid Switch Fuso SS-1504</option>
  <option value="21">Starter Assembly Fuso 4D30</option>
  <option value="22">Starter Assembly Isuzu V-10</option>
  <option value="23">Starter Assembly Hino JO8C</option>
  <option value="24">Starter Assembly Toyota 2C</option>
  <option value="25">Starter Assembly Isuzu 4BC2</option>
  <option value="26">Starter Carbon Brush Fuso 4D30 SM-56 </option>
  <option value="27">Starter Carbon Brush Isuzu X-10 SK-29</option>
  <option value="28">Starter Carbon Brush Fuso 8DC9 SM-J7</option>
  <option value="29">Starter Carbon Brush Isuzu 6BBI SK-14</option>
  <option value="30">Starter Carbon Brush Hino JO8 SD-81</option>
  </select>
</form>
<br>
<div id="txtid"><b>Details</b></div>

</body>
</html>
```

and the code for the php:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table {
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

table, td, th {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
}

th {text-align: left;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<?php
$q = intval($_GET['q']);

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','nht');
if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}

mysqli_select_db($con,"ajax");
$sql="SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE id = '".$q."'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

echo "<table>
<tr>
<th>Cost</th>
<th>Quantity</th>
</tr>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Selling_Price'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Quantity'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
mysqli_close($con);
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Please help because I really feel like I'm missing something.

Comment: check your console of what you are getting in ajax response and don't write the css in php page. Just echo the content and add css in the requesting page.

Comment: Missed something, maybe change your `$sql` query if you are dealing with `int`. Remove quotes.

Comment: The `$result` is only handled for the happy path, if the query fails (which could be from your description) any errors to unnoticed. Add error handling for failing queries and finding the error is more straight forward for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change this:

```
    if (this.readyState == 30 && this.status == 200) {
      alert(this.responseText);
      document.getElementById("txtid").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
```

to this:

```
if (this.readyState == 4) {
    if (this.status == 200 || this.status == 304) {
        alert(this.responseText);
        document.getElementById("txtid").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't notice that I had this.readyState=30 instead of 4! I just changed the value and its fine now. I knew I missed something small. . .  Thanks!